# ORACLE - ORA-01843: not a valid month in Oracle 19 ver

Tags: java, oracle

I am facing this issue while my system language change to Germany and run it as executable jar running
with

Here my date format is

```
TO_DATE('31-MAR-2021 12:06:08','dd-MON-yyyy HH23:MI:SS');
```

**No issue while running**

```
java -jar -Duser.language=en and -Duser.country=US %MY_JAR_NAME%
```

**Issue while running:**

```
java -jar  %MY_JAR_NAME%
```

```
    SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = null;
    String localStrDate = null;
    localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",new Locale("en", "US"));      
    calendarArg.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 2021);
    calendarArg.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, 2);
    calendarArg.set(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 31);        
    localDateFormat.setTimeZone(calendarArg.getTimeZone());
    localStrDate = localDateFormat.format(calendarArg.getTime());
    System.out.println("TO_DATE('" + localStrDate + "','dd-MON-yyyy HH23:MI:SS','NLS_DATA_LANGUAGE=American')");
```

Comment: Another good example why you should never rely on locale dependent date formats (or passing strings for date values around)

Comment: `HH23`??? shouldn't that be `HH24`?

Comment: Override the language: `TO_DATE('31-MAR-2021 12:06:08','dd-MON-yyyy HH23:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')`

Comment: When all your months in the database are English, simply set the `'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE'` parameter to `American`. The proper German MON for March would be `MÄR` for (`März`) ...

Comment: passed the parameter as simpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",new Locale("en"))

Comment: You need to check [timestamp literal](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062) and use implicit type conversion of timestamp to date instead of playing around with culture dependent data inside database.

Comment: `NLS_DATE_LANGAUGE` not `NLS_DATA_LANGUAGE`

Comment: Thanks the issue has resolved by passing  NLS_DATE_LANGAUGE  -@MT0 and @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Either use:

- a `DATE` literal and `INTERVAL` literal:

  ```
  DATE '2021-03-31' + INTERVAL '12:06:08' HOUR TO SECOND
  ```
- a `TIMESTAMP` literal:

  ```
  TIMESTAMP '2021-03-31 12:06:08'
  ```
- `TO_DATE` with numeric values:

  ```
  TO_DATE( '31-03-2021 12:06:08', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )
  ```
- `TO_DATE` with an explicit language:

  ```
  TO_DATE( '31-MAR-2021 12:06:08', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American' )
  ```
- or, skip converting the date to a string in Java and then back to a date in the database, and just pass the bind variable as a `DATE` data type using `java.time.Instant` and `oracle.sql.DATE`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=22ebdc83d07e4923f795252ea3b2ce13)*

Comment: Thanks the issue has resolved  with an explicit language